# Bash/Shell Download file from links in CSV File

Tags: bash, shell, unix

The CSV File has 2 columns in the following format:

Name; Links separated by , ;

for example

```
Product_1;www.example.com/product_1.png,www.example.com/product_2.png;
```

I am trying to make a while loop so it can download the images and rename them accordingly but can't figure it out

// Sorry, misexplained myself, I meant to say that I would like downloaded pictures to take the name in the first column with an _1, _2 etc if possible

This is what i've managed to get until now

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="$1"
while IFS=";" read f1 f2
do
  mkdir -p "$f1";
  wget -P "$f1" "$f2"
done < "$fname"
```

It works but only for a file, is there any method to make my life easier?

Comment: do you know the number of links you have? Or the number of links are fixed?

Comment: @ClintonLam Anywhere from 2 to 12-13 per name / object

Comment: and all links are separated with comma ‘,’?

Comment: have u tried read -r f1 f2 for recursive reading lines as well?

Comment: @ClintonLam Nope, have not tried -r, i'm not sure it will delimit the links by , ( as they are in the csv )

Comment: @ClintonLam What are you talking about? `-r `prevents escape sequences...

Comment: Please check my answer thanks @123 for remaining the wrong “” chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="$1"

# Loop through each line
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 _; do
    # Create directory
    mkdir -p "$f1"
    # Loop through comma separated links
    IFS=, read -r -a items <<< "$f2"
    for i in $items; do

        # Auto sequencing file name
        number=0; suffix="";
        while test -e "$f1/$f1$suffix.png"; do
            (( ++number ))
            suffix=$( printf -- '-%02d' "$number" )
        done
        outname="$f1/$f1$suffix.png"

        # Download file
        wget -P "$f1" -O "$outname" "$i"

    done
done < "$fname"
```

Comment: Very close to what I want, this puts them in the folder with the name I want instead of renaming them, any way to turn that around?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you add it in your question?

Comment: Putting them in a folder with the name from the first column is great, but I would like to rename the downloaded files with the name of the first tab of the CSV column aswell, for example if the name is toto and there are two files to download for it, they will be in the folder toto (already working) named toto_1 and toto_2

Comment: I see, will update that later for you. I am not at the computer right now. You may have to try it yourself for a while.I will be back soon.

Comment: @ClintonLam Thanks! I'll see if i can figure it out myself until then.

Comment: The code in this answer would benefit from being run through http://shellcheck.net/ and having the issues that finds fixed. Right now, an input file that put spaces in `f1` could provide arbitrary `wget` options, thus overwriting other files of its choice and otherwise performing mischief.

Comment: I'd also consider making it `read f1 f2 _`, so that we trim `f2` at any `;` rather than putting trailing content into that variable. Also better practice to read a string into an array with `IFS=, read -r -a items <<<"$f2"` -- that way you don't have a `*` replaced with a list of files in the current directory, as you do with `for i in $(...)`.